# C++ Converting const char* to char*

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to create a new class that takes a string, and converts it to a character array,then saves it to its private variable. So, I am trying to convert `const char*` to `char*` because I want to be able to modify its content.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass (const char* input) {
        // convert input to char* and assign it to carray
    }
private:
    char carray[];
};

int main() {
    MyClass mc = "StackOverflow";
}
```

I modified how the constructor takes the argument in various ways (`string& input`,`input.c_str()`, etc.), but all of them failed with one of the errors below.

```
error: conversion from ‘const char [14]’ to non-scalar type ‘MyClass’ requested

error: request for member ‘c_str’ in ‘s’, which is of non-class type ‘const char*’

error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]

error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘const char*’ to ‘char [0]’
```

I looked at several examples on SO, but I still could not figure out. How can I do this?

Comment: `char carray[];` is not valid as a class member in C++, is it? (you need to take a `char*` directly or copy it, which basically means to have a `std::string` member.

Comment: AFAIK, it's only valid in `extern` declaration.

Comment: `char carray[]` is not valid in C++0x, and I don't think that changed for C++11.  The size of the struct must be known at compile-time for the compiler to generate all of its navigation code.  `carray` would need to be a pointer to dynamic memory.  It appears his compiler interpreted that as a zero-length array, which is not permitted to be assigned, only referenced by address, but never read from or written to.

Comment: @John, thanks for point that out. I remember learning that some years ago. That is true, I can't use `char carray[]` there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't - if the original is indeed `const`, modifying its contents leads to undefined behavior.

Use a `std::string` instead:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass (const std::string& input) : carray(input){
    }
private:
    std::string carray;
};
```

In general, when approaching this sort of problem, you shouldn't even think about getting rid of the `const`, but rather think about **why** the `const` is there in the first place, and tackle the problem starting from there.

Comment: Hmm.. I think the OP wanted to make a copy of it?  Dunno.  Anyway, use string instead, yes.

Comment: But I want to be able to modify the content of the string passed to MyClass. Sure, I can probably make a copy of it and use that, but how?

Comment: @CookieMonster you can modify the `std::string carray` member in my sample just fine. `std::string` has a bunch of wonderful member methods for string manipulation.

Comment: I am getting this error `error: conversion from ‘const char [14]’ to non-scalar type ‘MyClass’ requested.` I thought string was immutable. If I modifty the string, wouldn't I be making a new string? That is why I wanted to have an array of characters.

Comment: @CookieMonster so you wrote the code I suggested and you get that error? "I thought string was immutable." maybe in Java. In C++, no. String literals are though. This is all explained in any C++ intro book.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, Yes, I used your code and I got that error. I come from Java background. I didn't know that strings are mutable in C++. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @CookieMonster can you post the code you used on www.ideone.com ?

Comment: @CookieMonster that's copy initialization - why not simply `MyClass str("StackOverflow");`?